# SQL join on CTE with multiple

Tags: sql, join, db2, common-table-expression

I have to combine two queries:

Query 1 - a simple inner join where query:

```
Select t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t2.c1

from s1.t2 t2
inner join s1.t1 t1 on t2.c6 = t1.c6

where t2.c5 >= '2014-01-01'
and t2.c5 >= '2014-01-01'
and t1.c4 = 'P'
```

This returns a table with 4 columns of course. let me draw it out here:

```
+----+----+----+-------+
| C1 | C2 | C3 | T2.C1 |
+----+----+----+-------+
|    |    |    |       |
```

Query 2 - With, then remove duplicates with a "partition by" statement:

```
WITH all_col1 (ONE, TWO) AS
(
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM Schema1.Table1
    UNION
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM Schema2.Table2
    UNION
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM Schema2.Table3
)
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT  ONE, TWO,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ONE ORDER BY ONE) duplicate_count
    FROM all_col1
) all_col1_w_duplicat_count
WHERE duplicate_count = 1
```

This returns two columns, with all the duplicates removed, (meaning, if column 1 has duplicates the extra rows are removed explicitly):

```
+-----+-----+
| ONE | TWO |
+-----+-----+
|     |     |
```

So what I'd like to see is the first query and the second query combined like this where TWO is added to the table where ONE matches C1:

```
+------+----+----+-------+-----+
| C1   | C2 | C3 | T2.C1 | TWO |
|(ONE) |    |    |       |     |
+------+----+----+-------+-----+
|      |    |    |       |     |
```

So, I've tried INTERSECT, adding placeholder rows. that returned empty.

I tried making query 1 a CTE as well then joining the two - got a myriad of errors trying that.

Here's the best I have been able to come up with so far - joining query 1 in with query 2 in its select statement:

```
--ALL COL1 WITH beginning 

WITH all_col1 (ONE, TWO) AS
(
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM Schema1.Table1
    UNION
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM Schema2.Table2
    UNION
    SELECT col1, col2
    FROM Schema2.Table3
)


--ALL COL1 SELECT duplicate_count

SELECT  *
FROM (
    SELECT  ONE, TWO,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ONE ORDER BY ONE) duplicate_count
    FROM all_col1


    -- added join opperation

    join (


        --SELECT from query 1

        Select t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t2.c1

        from s1.t2 t2
        inner join s1.t1 t1 on t2.c6 = t5.c6

        where t2.c5 >= '2014-01-01'
        and t2.c5 >= '2014-01-01'
        and t1.c4 = 'P' 


    -- finish join opperation

    ) as query1
    on all_col1.ONE = query1.c1    --  <----MOST IMPORTANT PART


-- finsih ALL COL1

) all_col1_w_duplicat_count
WHERE duplicate_count = 1
```

This, unfortunately, doesn't give me the results joined on the first column of each query as was trying to ask with `on all_col1.ONE = t1.c1`

Instead, it seems like it just gives me the WITH all_col1.

I know almost nothing about sql, What do I need to learn in order to join these two queries together correctly?

Comment: Can you please show sample data and desired results?  I can't follow what you're trying to do with just the queries alone...

Comment: Your second query is way over-complcated.  The `UNION` removes duplicates.

Comment: @Siyual Sorry, I should have added those visuals the first time. I added them now.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Well, perhaps the union removes duplicates if both values in a row match both values in another row or something, but it wasn't removing the duplicates of what I cared about. Column ONE had many duplicates with different corresponding values for column TWO. I just wanted 1 copy of column ONE and I didn't care which column two was included. for instance: if row 1 is ONE = "A" TWO = "12", and row 2 is ONE = "A" and TWO = "122" it includes both rows, I just want row 1.

Comment: @LegitStack - side note: your `ORDER BY ONE` will have no effect, since the ordering is _per partition_.  You're ordering by your grouping.  And, even if "any" result is acceptable, it's usually better to explicitly set something so the query is repeatable (or somebody is going to rely on the current behavior).  In that case, a `UNION ALL` and a regular `MIN` grouping would probably stand you in better stead.  One question, though; why do you have that date comparison twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider joining by two derived tables (subqueries in `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses) as your duplicate count includes both tables and not just one:

```
...
SELECT q.c1, q.c2, q.c3, q.t2_c1, a.[TWO]
FROM
  (
   SELECT *
   FROM (
          SELECT  ONE, TWO,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ONE ORDER BY ONE) duplicate_count
          FROM all_col1
        ) sub
   WHERE sub.duplicate_count = 1 
  ) a

INNER JOIN 
  (
   SELECT t1.c1, t1.c2, t1.c3, t2.c1 as t2_c1
   FROM s1.t2 t2
   INNER JOIN s1.t1 t1 on t2.c6 = t5.c6
   WHERE t2.c5 >= '2014-01-01'
    AND t2.c5 >= '2014-01-01'
    AND t1.c4 = 'P' 
  ) q

ON a.ONE = q.c1
```